# C++ template error no match for operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm working on a generic programming project.

Here is my code:

```
//header A.h
template<typename T>
struct Node {
    T key;
    bool operator>(Node<T>& node);
};

template<typename T>
bool Node<T>::operator>(Node<T>& node) {
    return (key > node.key); 
}
//-----------------------------------------
template<typename T>
struct Pair {
    T k1, k2;
    bool operator>(Pair<T>& p); 
}
template<typename T> bool Pair<T>::operator>(Pair<T>& p) {
    return (k1 > p.k1)&&(k2 > p.k2);
}
```

and, header B.h (includer header A.h as well):

```
class Tree {
    int i, j;
    Tree(int i, int j) : i(i), j(j) {}
    bool operator>(Tree& tree);
};
bool Tree::operator>(Tree& tree) {
    Pair<int> p1 = Pair<int>(i,j);
    Pair<int> p2 = Pair<int>(tree.i,tree.j);
    return (p1 > p2);
}
```

and finally the main function:

```
main() {
    Tree t1 = Tree(10,11);
    Tree t2 = Tree(1,2);
    Node<Tree> n1 = Node<Tree>(t1);
    Node<Tree> n2 = Node<Tree>(t2);
    if(n1 > n2) std::cout <<"ture\n"; //here i got warning: "instantiating from here"

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**
I got the warning: `candidates are: bool Tree::operator>(Tree&)` on the line:
`bool operator>(Pair<T>& p);`
Also, i have an error: `no match for ‘operator>’ in ‘((Node<Tree>*)this)->Node<Tree>::key > rightNode-` on the line: `return (key > node.key);`

**Question:** Why the compiler can't reach the `operator>` of `Tree` from the function of `operator>` of the `Node` struct? In other words, how can I fix that problem?

P.S. Since this is a less intuitive scenario, the title of the question might not be so accurate. If you have a better calling, I will be pleased to accept.

Comment: This is not your code.

Comment: What makes you think that? And how can this answer my question?

Comment: Er, maybe because several constructors and an access-specifier are missing and the definition of the `main` function misses an `int`? And finally, after adjustment, your code compiles just fine on both Clang 3.6 and GCC 5.1 - which compier are you even using?

Comment: right, this is just snippets of the code which captures the problem. i'm using `g++ 4.4.3` on `eclipse luna` on `Ubuntu 5.1`

Comment: *"this is just snippets of the code"* Cheers. Now what are we supposed to do with snippets that don't even reproduce the problem you have? Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), then ask.

Comment: [GCC 4.4.7 compiles this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YAC90miyQYbUQR0g).

Comment: I agree with the others that you really need to learn writing better questions. One thing that is already obvious is that you should really think about **adding `const`**. Your operators will not modify the object(s), so you should mark them `const` and also take the parameter by const-reference. Example declaration: `bool operator>(const Node<T>& node) const;`. Otherwise, several uses of the operators will be rejected with similar error messages as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Members of a class are private by default. Make `Tree` a `struct` and it should improve.